# Path to json object which contains an attribute or value

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have the following json array...

```
[
{ "class":"Identity", "id":5, "type":6 },
{ "class":"Combat", "damage":10.0 },
.
.
.
]

or

[
{ "class":"Combat", "damage":10.0 },,
{ "class":"Identity", "id":5, "type":6 }
.
.
.
]
```

I dont know the exact path to it, because its not deterministic.

I tried this `select json_search('one', "Identity") from...` but it only returns `$[0].class` which refers to the path of the attribute but not the path of the json object itself... which would be simply `$[0]`. This is the path i want to receive...

With what other statements may i find the path of the json object inside the array based on either its attribute or value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested:

```
mysql> set @j = '...your json example...';

mysql> select substring_index(json_unquote(json_search(@j, 'one', 'Identity')), '.', 1) as obj;
+------+
| obj  |
+------+
| $[1] |
+------+
```

Storing data in JSON when you want to use SQL expressions to search for specific sub-fields of the JSON is always going to be harder than storing data in a normal fashion.

Comment: Thanks a lot... been easier than i thought :D I hoped theres a build in function which wraps those three statements...

Comment: So how are you going to tell the difference between this JSON object and another JSON object that has the value 'Identity' but not in the 'class' field?

Comment: This will never happen :) Each "object" is plain data only and wont contain references to other json objects.... and each of those json objects only exist once per array

Comment: Remember this conversation when it _does_ happen. :-)

Comment: I will :D in case i can check if the attribute fits...